# getting GridView data from buttonField press?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

So I have a GridView for a C# web application, that has a Buttonfield, and when that button is clicked, I need to get the value of one of the fields for that row and store it in a variable for processing in some way.

However, neither the GridView nor the ButtonField seem to possess any means of doing this.

Can anyone recommend a way of getting data from a GridView, or if this is not possible, a different type of view that does offer this functionality, while still displaying a whole table (eg, not a DetailsView)

Comment: are you using ItemTemplate to populate GridView fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Check this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907626(v=vs.140).aspx.

- Define the CommandName of the Button.
- In the GridView Define the RowCommand Event and Check the CommandName.
- Get the Index of the Row.
- Get the Column with `GridView.Rows[index](columnIndex)`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `asp:TemplateField` like shown below then you can access the row content using `RowCommand`

Markup

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblCode" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CustomerID") %>'>
        </asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:ButtonField CommandName="AddCode" Text="Add New"/>
```

Code

```
protected void gvwSearch_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.CommandName == "AddCode")
    {
        var clickedButton = e.CommandSource as Button;
        var clickedRow = clickedButton.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
        var rows_lblCode = clickedRow.FindControl("lblCode") as Label;
        // now you can acccess all the label properties. For example,
        var temp = rows_lblCode.Text;

    }
}
```